# R - Triple Loop with if statement overjumps wrong lines

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am trying to perform a triple loop that contains an if-statement. Unfortunately, there must be a small mistake in my code, because it only gives me half of the result.

My dataframe is down below. I have 3 columns (ICD, Variables, Condition) that I am looping over. My aim is to create subdataframe out of my testframe that are containing all possible combinations out of this 3 columns, grouped in that 1 subframe. So basically the subframe should have all entries, that have the same ICD, Variable and Condition.

Then I want to create another dataframe (data_list), in which I want to summarize certain information of this subdataframe. Each row in the data_list should represent the information of one subdataframe.

To aviod dealing with empty dataframes or dataframes that are not of interest (Correlations smaller than 0.3 or higher -0.3 I added an if-statement.

I have the problem, that is giving me a correct output, but not the full output. In this case I get Oz1 and Oz2, but SON_PC4 and Year_PC5 are missing. Does anyone have an idea where my code is wrong?

```
vari_list = sort(unique(testframe$Variables))
icd_list = sort(unique(testframe$ICD))
condi_list = sort(unique(testframe$Conditions))

data_list = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0,ncol = 15))
colnames(data_list) = c("ICD", "Variable", "Condition", "Corr_max", "Corr_min","Corr_mean", "NCor", "Corr_max_lag", "Corr_min_lag", "Gen_Max", "GenMin", "AgeMax", "AgeMin", "LocMax", "LocMin")

for (a in 1:length(icd_list)) {
  for (b in 1:length(vari_list)) {
    for (c in 1:length(condi_list)) {
      b1 = paste0("######### Working on - ", icd_list[a])
      b2 = paste(b1, vari_list[b], sep = "+")
      b3 = paste(b2, condi_list[c], sep = "+")
      print(b3)
      #############################
      illness = icd_list[a]
      vari = vari_list[b]
      condi = condi_list[c]
      
      testframe_select = testframe[testframe$Variables == vari ,]
      testframe_select = testframe_select [testframe_select $ICD == illness ,]
      testframe_select = testframe_select [testframe_select $Conditions == condi ,]
      
      rownames(testframe_select) = NULL
      
      if (nrow(testframe_select )<1) next
      if (abs(max(testframe_select $Correlations)) <= 0.3) next
      
      Platz = nrow(data_list)
  
      max1 = testframe_select [which.max(testframe_select $Correlations),]
      min1 = testframe_select [which.min(testframe_select $Correlations),]
      
      data_list[Platz+1,1] = max1$ICD
      data_list[Platz+1,2] = max1$Variables
      data_list[Platz+1,3] = max1$Conditions
      data_list[Platz+1,4] = max1$Correlations
      data_list[Platz+1,5] = min1$Correlations
      data_list[Platz+1,6] = round(mean(testframe_select$Correlations),2)
      data_list[Platz+1,7] = nrow(testframe_select)
      data_list[Platz+1,8] = max1$Lag
      data_list[Platz+1,9] = min1$Lag
      data_list[Platz+1,10] = max1$Gender
      data_list[Platz+1,11] = min1$Gender
      data_list[Platz+1,12] = max1$Age
      data_list[Platz+1,13] = min1$Age
      data_list[Platz+1,14] = max1$Loc
      data_list[Platz+1,15] = min1$Loc

    }}}
```

My example dataframe

```
structure(list(Variables = c("Oz1", "Oz1", 
"Oz2", "Oz2", "Oz1", 
"Oz1", "SON_PC4", "SON_PC4", "Oz2", 
"Oz2", "SON_PC4", "SON_PC4", "Oz3", 
"Oz4", "PM3", "Year_PC7", 
"Oz3", "Oz4", "PM3", 
"Year_PC7", "PM1", "Year_PC7", "PM2", 
"Year_PC7", "PM1"), ICD = c("P35-P39", "P35-P39", 
"P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", 
"P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", 
"P35-P39", "P50-P61", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P35-P39", "P50-P61", 
"P35-P39", "P50-P61", "P35-P39", "P50-P61", "P35-P39"), Correlations = c(-0.37, 
-0.37, -0.35, -0.35, -0.34, -0.34, -0.31, -0.31, -0.31, -0.31, 
-0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, 
-0.28, -0.27, -0.27, -0.27, -0.27, -0.27), pvalue = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Days = c("184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "182", 
"182", "184", "184", "182", "182", "184", "184", "184", "184", 
"184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184", "184"
), Cases = c("125", "125", "125", "125", "107", "107", "107", 
"107", "107", "107", "123", "123", "125", "125", "125", "127", 
"125", "125", "125", "127", "107", "112", "107", "112", "125"
), Age = c("indifferent", "Baby", "indifferent", "Baby", "indifferent", 
"Baby", "indifferent", "Baby", "indifferent", "Baby", "indifferent", 
"Baby", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"Baby", "Baby", "Baby", "Baby", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"Baby", "Baby", "indifferent"), Gender = c("indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent"), Loc = c("indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent"), 
    Conditions = c("JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", 
    "SON", "SON", "JJA", "JJA", "SON", "SON", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", 
    "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", "JJA", 
    "JJA"), Lag = c("L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L6", "L6", "L5", 
    "L5", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", 
    "L7", "L7", "L7", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L7")), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think you should ask the question differently. Explain what is your goal by sharing sample data (which you already did) and expected output for that data. The triple loop is your attempt at solving this and what you think is the way. But this is not necessarily the only way this can be achieved, somebody might have a different way of achieving the same output. This is also called as [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: agree with Ronak above, please also share your expected output!